# Get collection of simple simple products in Magento2

Tags: magento2, simple-product

I'm working on a custom module to fetch the latest 10 simple products but it doesn't work. Could anyone have a look and see what i'm missing? Thanks

```
public function getProducts()
{
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
        ->setOrder('created_at')
        ->setPageSize(10);
    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
public function getProducts()
{
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
    $collection->getSelect()->order('created_at', \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_DESC);
    $collection->getSelect()->limit(10);
    return $collection;
}
```

In reference to our discussion from below, copy and paste this exactly as you see. The strange thing is that when I pasted your code into my IDE, it was going nuts with errors saying that it didn't recognize certain characters in your type hint for the product collection factory. It's strange but when I typed it out by hand, all errors went away. Copy and paste exactly as you see:

```
<?php

namespace Packt\HelloWorld\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Newproducts extends Template
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProducts()
    {
        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
        $collection->getSelect()->order('created_at', \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_DESC);
        $collection->getSelect()->limit(10);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: @QaiserAliBangash did this re-factored function help you out? If so, please go ahead and mark this answer as accepted so that other readers know that it is valid. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but unfortunately it doesn't work. It returns empty result

Comment: @QaiserAliBangash If possible, please post your entire class. I want to see what it extends from and I also want to see in your constructor where you declare the product collection factory. There has to be some other problem.  Also, have you cleared var/di and var/generation after each change? Is caching enabled or disabled? Are you in developer mode or production mode? These questions will help me fix this for you.

Comment: Yes i'm in developer mode, have cleared the cache and deleted the var/generation folder.

Comment: <code><?php
namespace Packt\HelloWorld\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Newproducts extends Template
{
    private $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }</code>

Comment: You need to change `private $_productCollectionFactory;` to `protected $_productCollectionFactory;` if you are not calling the function in the same exact class. So if your function gets called in a class that extends from Newproducts it won't work unless you change it to protected.

Comment: I tired with protected $_productCollectionFactory; but still no luck. I am not extending any other class from the current one, so don't think private $_productCollectionFactory; is an issue

Comment: strange. ill try something with your code as I am in M2 right now

Comment: it finally worked?

Comment: How it worked and what you have changed? It works when i assign 'configurable' to type_id and it shows only configurable products

Comment: I changed your context type hint to `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context` and I re-typed your type hint for `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` because I think it contained non-standard characters and as a result, the php compiler was not recognizing it.

Comment: Really strange. I copied your changes  but still it doesn't work. I don't think it's a non-standard characters issues because all other codes work fine

Comment: there were non-standard chars when i copied your code from the browser. anyways, what i posted should definitely work since i have tested it many times. there is some other problem preventing it from working on your installation and without some more info or a copy of the module you are building its really tough to say

Comment: At last it works. thanks for all of your time!

Comment: It's my pleasure. I am very curious though, what was the cause of the problem?

Comment: I had made a mistake while adding products. Instead of simple products i have created virtual products.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share another approach in order to retrieve the last 10 simple products.

You can use **ProductRepository** with **searchCriteria**.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class RecentProduct extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder
     */
    protected $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder
     */
    protected $sortOrder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder $sortOrder,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->sortOrder = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->sortOrder = $sortOrder;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProducts()
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setCurrentPage(1);
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setPageSize(10);

        $filters[] = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('type_id')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
            ->create();
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters($filters);

        $sortOrder = $this->sortOrder->setField('updated_at')->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_DESC);
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders([$sortOrder]);

        return $this->customerRepository->getList($this->searchCriteriaBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Comments:**

This code is not tested, but you have the code logic.

This avoid you to use Magento collection directly.